Google Play Games (Beta) PC VERSION Game crashes on launch error -1
Every time I try to launch any game on the google play games launcher for pc the game crashes right as I launch it.
I've enabled virtualization in my BIOS and I've also enabled hyper-v in my windows, I have reinstalled the google play launcher many times, launched it as administrator and launched it with my antivirus turned off. reinstal ed the google play launcher many times, launched it as administrator and launched it with my antivirus turned off.
Thanks in advance!
SPECS:
SO: Windows 11 Pro
CPU: I5-12400F
GPU: RX 6600 8GB
RAM: 24 GB
SSD: 256GB
HDD: 1TB

More detail needed. Either provide logs detailing the crash or screenshots
